# How to extract data from pdf image file with the coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, wand

How to extract text from PDF image file with in the coordinates, using 
python and with its external libraries.

```
from wand.image import Image as wi
from PIL import Image

pdf = wi (filename=("F:\cng-example-bill.pdf")
pdfImg = pdf.convert('jpg')
crop_img = pdfImg.crop((35, 20, 40, 35))
print(crop_imp)
```

the snippet of code trying to convert PDF file into jpg file, 
from jpg trying to extract data based on coordinates.
The program should give output(data) based on coordinates of a image file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pdf.convert('jpg')` line just clones the stack, and sets the format property. The `pdfImg.crop` returns `True` on success, and doesn't return any data. You might be able to rewrite the snippet as...

```py
from wand.image import Image as wi

pdf = wi(filename=("F:\cng-example-bill.pdf[0]")
pdf.crop(left=35, top=20, width=40, height=35)
crop_img = pdf.make_blob('jpg')
```

Note that `"F:\cng-example-bill.pdf[0]"` only decodes the first page of the PDF, and the crop area is a `40x35+35+20` region. The `crop_img` is a JPG file data, not pixel data, or pdf-text data.